# Updating a value from returned rows from SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

Using a single table `USERS`, I would like to update the top 20 values (based on `marks` column) of column `STATUS` which is currently **NULL** to **"Waiting"**.

Is this possible using an `Update` (only to affect the top 20 users and the rest should be made to **"N/A"**)?

Right now I can only think of

```
Update
  STATUS
from
  USERS
where
  STATUS is NULL
group by
  MARKS desc
LIMIT
  20;
```

But I get an error

EDIT:-

```
UPDATE  
  student  
SET  
  status = 'Waiting'  
where  
  branch in (  
    select  
      branch  
    from  
      (  
        select  
          branch  
        from  
          student  
        where  
          STATUS is NULL  
        order by  
          CGPA DESC  
        limit  
          1, 2  
      ) temp  
  )
```

I've tried this, but it updates all the rows not just the two that I want (the top 2 sorted on marks)

Comment: Please give table structure, especially primary key field details. It will help in formulating the query

Comment: what is the error reported?

Comment: Learn the syntax of `UPDATE`.  It's not even a valid syntax.

Comment: Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Primary key isnt particularly important in this query, I edited my post with another query that I tried that did run but gave me a result such that all rows were changed instead of the top two like I wanted
I had a look at the syntax and a few other topics and edited my question, apologies as I am new to this forum

Comment: @ShaunFernandez we need PK field name so that we can do self-join using that for update. Limit does not work in a subquery. So join is required to approach this problem from a derived table

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
UPDATE USERS SET status = 'Waiting' where ID in (select ID from USERS where STATUS is NULL order by MARKS DESC limit 1,20)
```

Comment: It says that this version of MySQL doesnt allow for limit inside such statements.I edited my post with something that did work but is giving me incorrect results

Comment: You can't use LIMIT in an "IN" subquery, but you can in a derived table, like UPDATE t1 JOIN (SELECT foo FROM t2 LIMIT 20) dt ON t1.id = dt.id SET t1.bar = 'bat';

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a850e/1

```
UPDATE users u
JOIN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM users
  WHERE `status` IS NULL
  ORDER BY marks desc
  LIMIT 20
) j 
ON u.id = j.id
SET `status`='WAITING';
```